# SQL. Looping through columns from different tables to calculate value

Tags: sql, for-loop, while-loop, case

I want to calculate how many drivers have drove too fast. I have a table
traffic.
In this table on each row I can see how many cars drove in different speed categories. For this issue I only need the columns amount_drivers1 until amount_drivers10.

I have ten different speed categories (for example the values of speed_categorie columns 1-10 are: 20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110) in the table speedcategories
These are different per way. For each row I have to find the speed categories per way. Speed_categorie1 is related to amount_drivers1, speed_categorie2 is related to amount_drivers2...

Then I have to use the column max_speed from the table MAX_SPEED. I have to loop through every speed_categorie column to see if the speed_categorie is above the max_speed column. If not do nothing, if yes the amount of cars from the traffic table (the value of the column amount_drivers) has to taken into the column 'to_hard'.

The relation between the max_speed, speed_categories and traffic tables are the id numbers. These are the foreign keys. This is the diagram:

[image: LRS of database]

For example the max_speed=60 (from the max_speed_table). Then only the the speed categories 70,80,90,100 and 110 (from speed_categorie table) are eligible. Then the amount of drivers from the amount_drivers6, amount_drivers7,amount_drivers8,amount_drivers9 andamount_drivers10 (from traffic table) have to go in the column 'to_hard'. So this is a sum of the columns amount_drivers6, amount_drivers7,amount_drivers8,amount_drivers9 andamount_drivers10 in this case. This sum must go in the column 'to_hard'.

Comment: While a standard approach for programming, loops are not the way for SQL.  You'll want to write a query that examines the rows all at once and use `Count ()`  to provide a summary.  Create an SQL fiddle with an example dataset and we can give you more advice.

Comment: You need to give us example data (say 10 rows max) for each of your 3 tables and then what results you would expect from those tables.  then we will be able to show you a solution.  Remember, SQL works with sets.  In other languages when you were working with a set you needed a loop.  You don't need a loop in SQL to work with a set.

Comment: Also your example does not make sense -- for example `ON ST.WAY=SC.WAY` -- WAY is not a column in these tables according to the link you posted.

Comment: I am working on it, give me some time

Comment: U are right Hogan. I've changed it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a good table structure. If you want to store this kind of data, it's best to create another key and store the `amount_drivers` columns as a single column over multiple rows. The same goes for `SPEED_CAT`. As it is, there isn't much reason to use the `SPEED_CATEGORIES` table since you have a fixed number of columns. However, just in case these values change, I've used them below.

Second, this is the best I can glean from your structure and desired output without data to support it. See the comments on your question.

```
select
    Trf.ID,
    (
        case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_1 then Trf.amount_drivers1 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_2 then Trf.amount_drivers2 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_3 then Trf.amount_drivers3 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_4 then Trf.amount_drivers4 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_5 then Trf.amount_drivers5 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_6 then Trf.amount_drivers6 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_7 then Trf.amount_drivers7 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_8 then Trf.amount_drivers8 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_9 then Trf.amount_drivers9 else 0 end
        + case when Spd.MAX_SPEED <= Cat.SPEED_CAT_10 then Trf.amount_drivers10 else 0 end
    ) TO_HARD
from
    TRAFFIC Trf
    join MAX_SPEED Spd Trf.MAX_SPEED_KEY = Spd.ID
    join SPEED_CATEGORIES Cat on Trf.SPEED_CATEGORIE_KEY = Cat.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SP first, `EXEC CheckOverSpeed 1` for get the total for way1, same for the rest, if you need this to be automated to get the list of all ways, let me know, but the first thing I could think of is using `cursor`, if you are familiar with this, you could make changes to my SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckOverSpeed

(@ID_input INT)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @amount_drivers1 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers2 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers3 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers4 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers5 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers6 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers7 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers8 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers9 INT
DECLARE @amount_drivers10 INT


DECLARE @SPEED_CAT1 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT2 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT3 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT4 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT5 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT6 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT7 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT8 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT9 INT
DECLARE @SPEED_CAT10 INT


DECLARE @MAX_SPEED_ID INT
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @SUM INT = 0

SELECT @ID = @ID_input, 
       @amount_drivers1 = T.amount_drivers1,
       @amount_drivers2 = T.amount_drivers2,
       @amount_drivers3 = T.amount_drivers3,
       @amount_drivers4 = T.amount_drivers4,
       @amount_drivers5 = T.amount_drivers5,
       @amount_drivers6 = T.amount_drivers6,
       @amount_drivers7 = T.amount_drivers7,
       @amount_drivers8 = T.amount_drivers8,
       @amount_drivers9 = T.amount_drivers9,
       @amount_drivers10 = T.amount_drivers10,

       @SPEED_CAT1 = S.SPEED_CAT1,
       @SPEED_CAT2 = S.SPEED_CAT2,
       @SPEED_CAT3 = S.SPEED_CAT3,
       @SPEED_CAT4 = S.SPEED_CAT4,
       @SPEED_CAT5 = S.SPEED_CAT5,
       @SPEED_CAT6 = S.SPEED_CAT6,
       @SPEED_CAT7 = S.SPEED_CAT7,
       @SPEED_CAT8 = S.SPEED_CAT8,
       @SPEED_CAT9 = S.SPEED_CAT9,
       @SPEED_CAT10 = S.SPEED_CAT10,

       @MAX_SPEED_ID = M.MAX_SPEED_ID

FROM
TRAFFIC as T 
INNER JOIN MAX_SPEED as M
ON M.MAX_SPEED_ID = T.ID
INNER JOIN SPPED_CATEGORIES as S
ON S.ID = T.ID
WHERE T.ID = @ID

SET @SUM = CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT1<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers1 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT2<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers2 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT3<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers3 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT4<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers4 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT5<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers5 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT6<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers6 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT7<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers7 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT8<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers8 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT9<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers9 END +
           CASE WHEN  @SPEED_CAT10<@MAX_SPEED_ID THEN 0 ELSE @amount_drivers10 END

PRINT 'The total number of over speed drivers for way '+CAST(@ID as varchar(50)) + ' is '+ CAST(@SUM as varchar(100)) 

END
```

Comment: Ty for your answer! I will try your solution now,

Comment: Keep me updated whether it works or not, since I do not have your tables, tell me if you have any error so I could debug xD

Comment: I remove the extra `@` in the last part of the SP, please check

Comment: But I never used a procedure. How can I check if the right values are stored?

Comment: hmm, there is some part went wrong, there should pop a value instead 'Command(s) completed successfully', let me check it first

Comment: Could you give the result of this :`SELECT * FROM
TRAFFIC as T 
INNER JOIN MAX_SPEED as M
ON M.MAX_SPEED_ID = T.ID
INNER JOIN SPPED_CATEGORIES as S
ON S.ID = T.ID
WHERE T.ID = 1`

Comment: max speed= 100. amount of drivers: 9 49 16 7 0 0 1 0 0 2.  Speed categories: 81 87 97 105 111 118 127 147 196 137

Comment: Sorry for the way im posting it

Comment: hmmm, looks fine to me, you could either try @Jeremy Fortune's answer, that is the same logical but more direct. what I did for you is just little bit dynamic (kind of ...)

Comment: Ty for your help LONG. The answer of @jeremy fortune works. Only with his solution I see the results in SQL server of each record 9 times. U have any idea why?

Comment: TRY THIS `TRAFFIC Trf
    join MAX_SPEED Spd Trf.ID = Spd.MAX_SPEED_ID
    join SPEED_CATEGORIES Cat on Trf.ID = Cat.ID`

Comment: Ty for your time and help LONG! I works perfectly now!